# The "Report ad" functionality doesn't work; the URL it attempts to post to results in a 500 error

Tags: bug, status-review, advertising, error-message

I'm trying to report an ad (for reasons that are not relevant here). I open the "Report Ad" dialog, fill in the information required, including a screenshot of the ad itself, but the attempt to submit the report fails.

I see an error message that says nothing more than "Error uploading ad report". No other details are provided.

[image]

When I investigate more thoroughly using my browser console, I see that it is failing to access the URL `https://stackoverflow.com/ads/report-ad/submit` with an error code of 500. Visiting this URL manually, I see a Stack Overflow "Page not found" error page.

[image]

Comment: i noticed this a month or two ago, but didn't care enough to make a meta post about it.

Comment: I reproduce this, and have reproduced it on multiple prior occasions.